# How do I set my datetimepicker date?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, datepicker

I'm writing a program in c++/cli visual studio 2010 and I don't know how to set a specific date into my datetime picker.

I also want to know how do I set the default day to today, so you can't go to dates that has already passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) property to set the current date/time, and [`MinDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) to set the earliest date that can be selected.

```
dateTimePicker1->MinDate = DateTime::Today;
```